# VLC: is it possible to auto record when Livestreamer opens a stream?

Tags: batch-file, stream, record, vlc, twitch

I've installed [Livestreamer](http://docs.livestreamer.io/install.html) and [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) and have saved the following as "livestreamer_start.bat" on my desktop:

```
 livestreamer twitch.tv/netherrealm source
```

So when I open that file it automatically opens VLC and plays the Twitch stream. I can then hit record, in VLC, manually. But I'm needing to have the record button automatically activated/pressed (I'm wanting to use Windows Task Scheduler to activate the .bat file at a later time).

I tried adding this to a separate .bat file ([via the docs](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch06.html)):

```
--sout file/mp4:stream.mp4
```

and running it after the first .bat, but nothing happens...I know I'm not using it correctly or missing something.

Is there a simple command/way to have VLC auto record the stream it is currently playing?

Answer (score 0):

In short:

livestreamer sending to stdout -> piped into -> vlc reading from stdin:

Here is an example that works:

```
livestreamer --loglevel debug "hlsvariant://http://keshethlslive-lh.akamaihd.net/i/c2n_1@195269/master.m3u8" best --stdout | vlc - -vvv --sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,fps=30,width=576,acodec=mp2a,scale=1,channels=2,deinterlace,audio-sync}:standard{access-file,mux=ps,dst="test1.mpg"}
```

You can play around with params.

Comment: Thanks. Gonna give that a go right now. But is there not just a command to get VLC to record what's already open, though? Separate from anything to do with Livestreamer? A command as simple as (please forgive my naivety): "vlc record" and it would use the settings already set for what happens when the record button is manually pressed?